# What would be an adequate test for a multivariate distribution to test for stationarity?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, stationarity, unit-root

I have monthly returns of a certain portfolio with $d$ assets and I want to check it for stationarity;

More precisely , I want to test whether the multivariate distribution of

$$(X^t_{1}, \ldots, X^t_{d})$$

is equal to the distribution of

$$(X^{t+n}_{1}, \ldots, X^{t+n}_{d})$$,

with $t$ and $d$ some arbitrary integers...

Now, as I am not so good with those things, I read a little bit in the literature - some divide it into intervals and just check for variance, mean, covariance;

Some use some unit root test on each of assets separately, see e.g. here

[Correct Unit Root Testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160796/correct-unit-root-testing)

But then for example, the correlation (or more general, the dependence between the assets might change without the test capturing it)

So what is the most widely used thing to test some multivariate dataset for stationarity? I am a bit lost here...

I'm very happy about any answers

Comment: See:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79187/stationarity-in-multivariate-time-series,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423483/multivariate-stationarity-cointegration-test,   https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb40&q=testing%20stationarity%20for%20multivariate%20time%20series&lookup=0&hl=en